# How to solve - The element type meta must be terminated by the matching end-tag </meta>

Tags: java, xml, weather

I tried to wrote a code for weather app and i have this error:

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 27; The element type "meta" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".
>   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse (AbstractSAXParser.java:1239)
>   at main.Weather.GoogleWeather.getWeather(GoogleWeather.java:38)
>   at main.Main.main(Main.java:12)

I don't know if I set everything properly

My Code:

```
public class GoogleWeather extends Weather{
    private final String googleWeatherURL = "http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=";
    public GoogleWeather(String city, String locationPoints) throws IOException, SAXException {
        super(city, locationPoints);
    }

    @Override
    public void getWeather() {
        String location = "Warsaw, PL";
        String link = googleWeatherURL + location;
        link = link.replace(" ", "%20");

        try {
            URL urlObject = new URL(link);
            InputStream in = urlObject.openStream();
            XMLReader xmlReader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();

            XMLHandler xmlHandler = new XMLHandler();
            xmlReader.setContentHandler((ContentHandler) xmlHandler);

            InputSource inSource = new InputSource(in);

            xmlReader.parse(inSource);

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And

```
public class XMLHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    private ArrayList<Integer> night = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> day = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private ArrayList<String> days = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> conditions = new ArrayList<String>();


    public XMLHandler() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void startDocument() {
        System.out.println("Start document");
    }


    @Override
    public void endDocument() {
        System.out.println("End document");
    }


    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String name, String qName, Attributes atts) {
        if (qName.compareTo("day_of_week") == 0) {
            String day = atts.getValue(0);
            System.out.println("Day: " + day+ " ; ");
            this.days.add(day);
        }
        if (qName.compareToIgnoreCase("low") == 0) {
            int night = Integer.parseInt(atts.getValue(0));
            System.out.print("Low: " + night + " ; ");
            this.night.add(night);
        }
        if (qName.compareToIgnoreCase("high") == 0) {
            int high = Integer.parseInt(atts.getValue(0));
            System.out.print("High: " + high + " ; ");
            this.day.add(high);
        }
        if (qName.compareToIgnoreCase("condition data") == 0) {
            String conditions = atts.getValue(0);
            System.out.print("Conditions: " + conditions + " ; ");
            this.conditions.add(conditions);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried what this URL responds when you request it, before you start pushing it through an XML parser?

The API you're trying to use has been decommissioned for years and Google just gives you a 301 and serves an HTML webpage along in case the caller doesn't realize it just received a 301.

This service does not exist anymore, you cannot use it, and the URL you're trying to fetch won't provide you with XML, hence why a XML parser is giving you an error.